# Optimistic Locking with Spring Data using a subfield Version

Tags: java, rest, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I know that if I include the @Version annotation as a field directly in the class to persist, then Optimistic Locking works out of the box. However, I do not want to change my data model and I am trying the solution described below.
In a Spring Data MongoDB REST application, the data model for the entities is the following one:

```
@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    String id;
    @JsonProperty(value = "firstName")
    String firstName;
    @JsonProperty(value = "lastName")
    String lastName;
    @JsonProperty(value="metadata")
    MetaData metaData;

    //GETTER AND SETTERS

}
```

My purpose is to annotate the field Version of the MetaData class in order to use Optimistic Locking in the class Person.

```
public class MetaData {

    @JsonProperty(value = "createdAt")
    private String createdAt;

    @JsonProperty(value = "createdBy")
    private String modifiedAt;

    @JsonProperty(value = "createdAt")
    private String createdAt;

    @JsonProperty(value = "createdBy")
    private String modifiedAt;

    @JsonProperty(value = "version")
    @Version
    private Integer version;

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
}
```

The above solution does not work. Is there some way to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `WriteConcern` is set to `ACKNOWLEDGED`

Comment: MetaData and Person are generated from JSON files. In the case of working with MongoDB, I can choose to make MetaData a separate document or not.